# How to achieve many-to-many association in Ecto with primary keys?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have three tables, `permissions`, `permission_sets` and their junction table `permission_set_permissions`.

The `permissions` table hold `Permission` model data, and the size of this table is deterministic. To clarify, we are not going to insert any data to this table when application is running.

The model `PermissionSet` persisted in `permission_sets` table has many-to-many relationship with `Permission`.

Normally, you would create a `PermissionSet` with that request:

```
POST /api/v1/permission_sets/

{
    "permission_set": {
        "name": "default",
        "description": "Default permission set.",
        "permissions": [
            {
                "type": "all",
                "required_grant_power": 200,
                "controller_name": "Elixir.MyApp.UserController",
                "controller_action": "index"
            },
            {
                "type": "one",
                "required_grant_power": 200,
                "controller_name": "Elixir.MyApp.UserController",
                "controller_action": "show"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

However, this would create new `Permission`s with given data.

In my case, I'd like to reuse the existing permissions with their primary keys. An example would be:

```
POST /api/v1/permission_sets/

{
    "permission_set": {
        "name": "default",
        "description": "Default permission set.",
        "permission_ids": [
            2,
            7
        ]
    }
}
```

Do you have any suggestion on implementing this? Should I create a new model named `PermissionSetPermission` representing junction table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
  permissions = 
    Permission
    |> where([p], p.id in ^params[:permission_ids])
    |> Repo.all

  struct
  |> cast(params, [:name, :description])
  |> put_assoc(:permissions, permissions)
end
```

Comment: It would be better to do a `where: permission.id in ^params[:permission_ids]` query if you mostly expect to get more than 1 id in the `permission_ids` list.

Comment: @Leviathlon I edited my answer and added improvement mentioned by Dogbert